# How can i use uitableview cell for performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, cell

I started to learn Swift 2 weeks ago. With some courses and youtube videos, I learn basics of uitableview but I couldn't get how can I use specific table view cell like a button.

What I wanna do?

I am trying to use the sidebar menu(https://github.com/yannickl/FlowingMenu) for my project, everything is cool and working okay instead of using cells.

In every basic tutorial people showing how to use segue with uitableview but they only use 2 pages and independent from cell value, no matter what text in your cell it calls segue for the second controller.

I want to use the sidebar menu with cells and if my cell value is "main menu" I want to perform "toMainMenu" segue.

I only know using cells with arrays don't know is there any other way for work with cells, and my main goal is cell-specific segue.

I watched a lot of tutorials but can't find anything useful for me.

```
import UIKit
```

import FlowingMenu

class SideBarMenu: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var surnameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var topBar: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet weak var backButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var userTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!
let CellName  = "Menu"
let mainColor = UIColor(hex: 0xC4ABAA)
var sections = ["Main Menu", "Settings", "Profile"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userTableView.delegate = self
    userTableView.dataSource = self
    nameLabel.text = Helper.name
    surnameLabel.text = Helper.surname

    topBar.tintColor              = .black
    topBar.barTintColor           = mainColor
    topBar.titleTextAttributes    = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 22)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
    ]
    userTableView.backgroundColor = mainColor
    view.backgroundColor          = mainColor
}



// MARK: - Managing the Status Bar

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

// MARK: - UITableView DataSource Methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.row]
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = mainColor
    return cell
}

// MARK: - UITableView Delegate Methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Select row at")
}
@IBAction func profileButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfile", sender: nil)
}
```

}

I want to perform "toSettings" segue when "Settings" cell clicked.

Comment: It would be helpful to post some of your code here pointing at the place you have a question about or where you're seeing a problem.

Comment: @BobHy added and edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the UITableViewDelegate protocol method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` as below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   switch sections[indexPath.row] {
   case "Main Menu":
      performSegue(with: "toMainMenu", sender: nil)
   case "Settings":
      performSegue(with: "toSettings", sender: nil)
   case "Profile":
      performSegue(with: "toProfile", sender: nil)
   }
}
```

If you need to configure or pass some data to the destination controller, you can override the controller's `prepare(for:sender:)` method to get a reference, for example:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "toMainMenu" {
      let dvc = segue.destination as! MenuViewController
      // now you have a reference
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, your menu is a tableView, so you need to segue to the view you wanna open in the table didSelectAt

Comment: I just want to use sidebar menu but i dont know how table cells work with segues

Answer (score 0):

You can use override prepare for segue. so when you link your views with a segue you set an identifier for each one and can call whatever you need from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible to give me a little example ?

Comment: @kemalsanli Sure so here is something I have done in the past 

`override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toMainMenu" {
            //Add any code here to pass data if needed to this controller
                present(MainMenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        if segue.identifier == "toAnotherViewController" {
            //Add any code here to pass data if needed to this controller
                present(AnotherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }`